# SQL Sort by date and optional group

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, mysql-8.0

Is it possible to sort by date, but maintaining groups (if given) in one set?

Example data set:

```
id | date       | group
————————————————————————————
7  | 2021-04-10 |
6  | 2021-04-02 | GGGG
5  | 2021-04-01 |
4  | 2021-04-01 | GGGG
3  | 2021-03-31 | GGGG
2  | 2021-03-30 |
1  | 2021-03-28 | XYZ
```

Expected output:

```
id | date       | group
————————————————————————————
7  | 2021-04-10 |
6  | 2021-04-02 | GGGG
4  | 2021-04-01 | GGGG
3  | 2021-03-31 | GGGG
5  | 2021-04-01 |
2  | 2021-03-30 |
1  | 2021-03-28 | XYZ
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8+?  If so, then give Gordon's answer below a try.

Comment: Unfortunately this question got closed, even though I was specific and posted examples - and it already got an accepted answer. It would be great if it could be reopened by somebody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, because you are treating `NULL` as a separate group.  So, one method is:

```
order by max(date) over (partition by coalesce(group, -id)) desc,
         group, date desc
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd1e9be887ebfc3214114d9f4726b60d) is a db<>fiddle.

This works because values are positive for both columns, so using negative values won't interfere with the assignment of unique partitions.

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL, one possibility is a correlated subquery:

```
order by (select max(t2.date) 
          from t t2
          where t2.group = t.group or
                (t.group is null and t2.id = t.id))
         ),
         group, date desc
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion (with MySQL 8.0 this time), unfortunately I get the same output as with `order by group desc, date desc` // edit: it works with selecting it as a field and sorting by that field afterwards

Comment: @Simon . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  It works just as advertised.

Comment: thanks for the fiddle. Unfortunately it only works with selecting as a field (8.0.21). As I don't have the time to debug this case for now, that's perfectly fine for me.